# HP ILO4 with shared network port always disconnect session and timeout

Tags: hp, ilo

Recently, i purchased several HP DL 120 GEN9 with ILO4 advanced features in shared network port. Unfortunately, it is being a hell for manage it. Randomly it disconnect me from the remote console .net or java and web (it lost connectivity, at least 5-6 icmp pings). For load virtual media it happens too, is almost impossible to load a ISO with virtual media without timeout or errors.

Someone experienced this problems with HP ILO3 or ILO4? My ILO FIRMWARE is 2.30

Thank you!

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the HPE Customer Advisory written about the failure of installing OS using iLO Virtual Media if iLO is configured to the Shared Network Port.  It will explain why there are errors and time-outs.  It also appears that the issue you were having was resolved on another forum.  I hope this information helped anyways.  The information was provided by HPE sources.

Link to HPE consumer advisory: http://h20565.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c02227387
Link to answered question on WebHostingTalk forum: http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=1547279

Veena G

HPE Employee